# Openssl cms verify signature with timestamp and crl

Tags: openssl, digital-signature, timestamp, crl, cms

I've used OpenSSL cms to sign the data and generate a detached signature. As per my requirements, I need to timestamp the signature as well, so that if the certificate expired, verification of signature can be done. The generated timestamp is also in a detached format. I've also generated the CRL after revoking the certificate.

> NOTE: For testing purpose, I’ve created my own CA authority using OpenSSL

For signing data:

`openssl cms -sign -binary -in test_data.tgz -md sha256 -signer my-cert.pem -inkey my-cert.key -out test_data.cms -outform DER`

For timestamping signature: (Used freetsa.org as a TSA authority)

```
openssl ts -query -data test_data.cms -no_nonce -sha256 -cert -out test_data.tsq
curl -H "Content-Type: application/timestamp-query" --data-binary '@test_data.tsq' https://freetsa.org/tsr > test_data.tsr
```

Now for the verification part as per my understanding from RFC3161 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3161#page-20) following procedure can be used to verify the authenticity of the digital signature.

1. Verify timestamp token:

`openssl ts -verify -in test_date.tsr -queryfile date_tsr.tsq -CAfile cacert.pem -untrusted tsa.crt`

`openssl ts -verify -data test_data.cms -in test_data.tsr -CAfile cacert.pem -untrusted tsa.crt`

2. Fetch the timestamp:

`openssl ts -reply -in test_date.tsr -text`

```
  > Time stamp: Apr 24 13:09:25 2020 GMT (Example)
```

3. Convert timestamp to Unix epoch time:

`date -d “Apr 24 13:09:25 2020 GMT” +%s`
> 1587733765

4. Verify the signature againt timestamp and the certificates via openssl cms

`openssl cms -verify -binary -verify -in test_data.cms -content test_data -CAfile ca-chain.cer -inform DER -out /tmp/tmp.data -attime 1587733765`

Everything works until crl (Certificate revocation list) comes into the picture.  What I know is that If the certificate (my-cert.pem in this case) has been revoked and if the “Invalidity Date” is after the timestamp data, the signature should still be valid. But with OpenSSL cms -verify it is not working as expected or it is not supported.

1. Revoke certificate:

`openssl ca -config openssl.conf -revoke my-cert.pem -crl_reason key -crl_reason keyCompromise -crl_compromise 20200422140925Z`

> Compromise date is after the timestamp date.

2. Verify the signature with crl and timestamp

`openssl cms -verify -binary -verify -in test_data.cms -content test_data -CAfile ca-chain.cer -inform DER -out /tmp/tmp.data -attime 1587733765 -crl_check`

> output: CRL is not yet valid

I think OpenSSL is comparing the “Last Update” date of CRL instead of “Invalidity date” with the date mentioned in -attime argument, i.e. 1587733765 dues to which it shows “CRL is not yet valid”.

3. Removing “-attime”

`openssl cms -verify -binary -verify -in test_data.cms -content test_data -CAfile ca-chain.cer -inform DER -out /tmp/tmp.data -crl_check`

> Output: Certificate revoked

So how do I verify the signature with CRL and timestamp in OpenSSL cms?
The only way I see is to fetch the “Invalidity Date” manually from CRL and compare it with the timestamp and act accordingly.